# Movable window of fixed length of time - SQL

Tags: sql, date, window

I have a database of about 100 million customer relation records and 3 million distinct clients

I need to write a SQL script to work out which clients have registered 5 or more complaints within 30 days of each other, over the entire history of the client

I thought that a window function would be the answer but I haven't had any luck

Any ideas would be useful, but efficient ones would be even better, as I have low system priority and my codes takes hours to run.

Comment: sample data and table structures would be useful.

Comment: Also, which database?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server with T-SQL. Sample data is: CustomerNumber, RecordEntryDate, ContactType etc. Very simple, I'm just querying one table to see which customers have ever made 5 complaints or more within a 30-day window - but I can't work out how to do that